# How do you do depth first iteration on a very wide array

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, depth-first-search

I am using an input list such as `numbers = [4, 7, 2]` (shortened for simplicity).

Each value in the list is passed through a dictionary to get a list of possible strings:

```
The Dictionary:  
buttons_dict = {}
buttons_dict[2] = ['A', 'B', 'C']
buttons_dict[3] = ['D', 'E', 'F']
buttons_dict[4] = ['G', 'H', 'I']
buttons_dict[5] = ['J', 'K', 'L']
buttons_dict[6] = ['M', 'N', 'O']
buttons_dict[7] = ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S']
buttons_dict[8] = ['T', 'U', 'V']
buttons_dict[9] = ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

Then I go bredth first through the input list, adding every possible character input to an output list of strings:

```
def add_letters(button, arr):

    letters_to_add = buttons_dict[button]
    longer_arr = []
    for possible_string in arr:
        new_possible_strings = []
        for letter in letters_to_add:
            new_possible_strings.append(possible_string + letter)
        longer_arr.extend(new_possible_strings)
    return longer_arr

letters = ['']
for i in numbers:
    #print(i)
    #print(letters)
    letters = add_letters(i, letters)
```

So the output strings would be

```
['GPA', 'GPB', 'GPC', 'GQA', 'GQB', 'GQC', 'GRA', 'GRB', 'GRC', 'GSA', 'GSB', 'GSC', 'HPA', 'HPB', 'HPC', 'HQA', 'HQB', 'HQC', 'HRA', 'HRB', 'HRC', 'HSA', 'HSB', 'HSC', 'IPA', 'IPB', 'IPC', 'IQA', 'IQB', 'IQC', 'IRA', 'IRB', 'IRC', 'ISA', 'ISB', 'ISC']
```

You can see how this list gets very long very quickly as we increase the length of the input list. Originally I was finding every possible output string and then iterating through them and using this function below to get the score for each string. (The details of how this work doesn't matter, I'm just including it for context.)

```
 def find_score(string):
    score = 0
    for letter_index in range(len(string) - 1):
        letter_1 = string[letter_index]
        letter_2 = string[letter_index + 1]
        #print('Letter combo: ({}, {})'.format(letter_1,letter_2))
        score += P[numbers_dict[letter_1]][numbers_dict[letter_2]]
    return score
```

Instead of my current bredth first method of creating every single possible string input. I want to create 1 string, then calculate it's score, then create a 2nd string, calculate it's score and compare it to previous scores ect ect for all possible strings.

Can someone suggest a method for doing this?

Comment: itertools.product?

Answer (score 1):

So the best way I could come up with is a recursive method - it builds your strings "depth-first" and keeps track of the highest-scoring string and its score. Here's the code I added in:   (NOTE: I used a different find_score() since I don't have your `numbers_dict`)

```
def find_score(string):
    score = sum([ord(a) for a in string])
    return score

def rec_strbuilder(numbers, str_so_far):
    if len(numbers) == 0:
        print("%s => %s" % (str_so_far, find_score(str_so_far)))
        return (str_so_far, find_score(str_so_far))
    this_num = numbers.pop(0)
    these_buttons = buttons_dict[this_num]
    best_score = -1
    best_str = ""
    for button in these_buttons:
        new_str = "%s%s" % (str_so_far, button)
        (result_str, result_score) = rec_strbuilder([number for number in numbers], new_str)
        if result_score > best_score:
            best_score = result_score
            best_str = result_str
    return (best_str, best_score)
        
        

numbers = [4,7,2]
best_str, best_score = rec_strbuilder(numbers, "")
print("Best String: %s, %s points" % (best_str, best_score))
```

OUTPUT:

```
GPA => 216
GPB => 217
GPC => 218
GQA => 217
GQB => 218
GQC => 219
GRA => 218
GRB => 219
GRC => 220
GSA => 219
GSB => 220
GSC => 221
HPA => 217
HPB => 218
HPC => 219
HQA => 218
HQB => 219
HQC => 220
HRA => 219
HRB => 220
HRC => 221
HSA => 220
HSB => 221
HSC => 222
IPA => 218
IPB => 219
IPC => 220
IQA => 219
IQB => 220
IQC => 221
IRA => 220
IRB => 221
IRC => 222
ISA => 221
ISB => 222
ISC => 223
Best String: ISC, 223 points
```